# database access VS lan access

Tags: performance

In a program, there are times when I can retrieve the same data either on a shared database or on a server connected in a lan. Which one should I choose regarding speed (and other considerations maybe) ?

An opened connection to the database AND an opened socket are already available when I need to make that decision.

Comment: What kind of server? What kind of database? What kind of data? Where is the database located?

Comment: It is a real question that I need to answer in a real program.

Comment: @Joel, you might want to read the description of the close reason.  "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."  You haven't given enough information to answer this question with anything other than "Well, it depends."  You can start by editing the answers to cularis' post into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependent on how you have setup access to your database, they will probably both use TCP/IP to access either.  So, the performance will be roughly the same.  If you have a file with the data in, you have to open the file and then read the contents.  Comparing that to a database connection, you have to open a database connection and execute some SQL to get the results.  I actually think that the main part of your question relies on what type of data your are actually wanting to store.